# Cannot find module 'glob' after building NW.js app

Tags: node.js, npm, glob, nwjs

I am facing a problem where if I build my NW.js app. If I run `npm run dev` my app works just fine.
But after building it with `npm run prod` the app cannot find module `glob`. You can see the console message below.

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:943 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'glob'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\csics\AppData\Local\Temp\nw28072_148657420/html/server.html
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:943:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:782:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1015:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at self.require (<anonymous>:11:26)
    at self.require (<anonymous>:11:26)
    at chrome-extension://cfkggdecgdmblbpgpmegjhkaeocljjae/js/handler.js:3:12
```

My package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "nwjs_log_app",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nw src/",
    "prod": "nwbuild -p win64 -f -o ./build src/"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "glob": "^7.1.6",
    "nw": "^0.50.2-sdk"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nw-builder": "^3.5.7"
  }
}
```

I tried to install glob everywhere but still not working.
I installed it globally with `npm i glob -g`, still the same error.

Tell me if anything else helps.